# Is "ing" with this verb (brim) form a gerund or a noun?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

I was looking for the definition of "brimming" and I found it "To be abundantly filled or supplied" 
And those examples on it
A monument brimming with tourists.
Workers brimming with pride.
according to thefreedictionary.com
My question: Is "Brim + ing" a  verb or a noun?

Answer (score 1):

> *a monument brimming with tourists*.
>
> *workers brimming with pride*.

"Brimming" is a verb. It has none of the properties of indisputable nouns, e.g. it can't take a determiner (* *the brimming*), and  nor can it be modified by an adjective (* *big brimming*"), but it can be modified by adverbs (which can't modify nouns), e.g. *seriously / happily brimming with pride*.

In your examples *brimming with tourists / pride* is a gerund-participial clause modifying *monument / workers*. The meaning is similar to the relative clauses *... which is brimming with tourists / ... who are brimming with pride*